# Подключение базы данных к проекту Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, база-данных

Как подключить БД к проекту? Все, что нашел в инете, подключают через `localhost` у меня она лежит файлом формата `example.db` и через что её можно дальше парсить.

Comment: localhost это часть адреса БД, а не подключения. Подключайтесь через jdbc парсите хибернейтом или spring data или jdbc или чем угодно другим =)

Answer (score 0):

1. Для десктоп приложения: [Connecting to MySQL Using the JDBC DriverManager Interface](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html#connector-j-examples-connection-drivermanager)
2. Для веб-приложения: [Connection Pooling with Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html#connector-j-examples-connectionpool-j2ee)

Соединение с базой данных происходит с помощью [JDBC API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html). Connector/J - это, в данном случае, реализация поставщиком MySQL JDBC API. Это jar-файл, который нужно скачать и подключить к проекту.